# creating drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I am a developer in training and I was trying to get this code to show a drop down menu when hovering over the list items "Music" and "Podcasts". But I can't seem to get it to work, what am I doing wrong?
I found some people doing the same thing, but my list never shows, which is logical of course because of the `display: none;` but I would like it to show after hovering over Music or Podcasts. Sorry, but I am still learning if it is messy/bad.

```css
 body {
 
 
 background-image: url(../images/top.png), url(../images/achtergrond.png);
 background-size: cover ;
 font-family: 'Neucha', cursive;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 
    }


    img {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 400px;
 
     }

    .navbar{
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
     }

    .list{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 35px;
     }

    li:hover .sublist-music a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
     }

    li{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 30%;
     }

    li:hover{
    background-color: #A1CCB6;
     }

    .sublist-music{
    display: none;
     }

    .sublist-podcasts{
    display: none;
     }
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/test.css">
 <title>banana split</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Neucha&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

    <body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="list">
            <li> <a>Home</a></li>
            <li> <a>Music</a></li>
                <div class="sublist-music">
                    <a href="/pages/test.html">Shows</a>
                    <a href="/pages/test.html">Live</a>
                </div>
            <li> <a>Podcasts</a></li>
                <div class="sublist-podcasts">
                    <li>Plants</li>
                    <li>Food</li>
                    <li>Youtubers</li>
                    <li>Mindfull</li>
                </div>
            <li> <a>Live</a></li>
            <li> <a>About us</a></li>
            <li> <a>Contact</a></li>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Music 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="/pages/test.html">Shows</a>
                <a href="/pages/test.html">Live</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#news">Live</a>
  
  <a href="#news">About us</a>
</div>
```

Reference link : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown_navbar.asp

Answer (score 0):

```css
 body {
  font-family: 'Neucha', cursive;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
    font-family: monospace;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border-radius: 30%;
  background-color: white;
}
  
li a {
  color: #000;
}

li:hover,
li:focus-within {
    background-color: #A1CCB6;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li:focus-within a {
  outline: none;
}

ul li ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    min-width: 5rem;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover > ul,
ul li:focus-within > ul,
ul li ul:hover,
ul li ul:focus {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block
}

ul li ul li {
    clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Music</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Shows</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Live</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Podcast</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Plants</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Youtubers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mindful</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Live</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```